# How to set title as username of webpage that he or she gives in textbox using .net in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

Design a webpage which has textbox and a button. User will enter
his/her name in the textbox. On the click event of the button
name of the user and current date time will be displayed on the
titlebar of the web page. (Using Literal control).

Comment: Try adding some code to show us what you have tried.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: You can comment below the answer as well. Can you show the code that you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Hookup on [click event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8) for button. On post back get the [string from the text box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8) and set it on literal control.

```
void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    literalControl.Text = $"{Server.HtmlEncode(textbox1.Text)} - {DateTime.Now}";
}
```

***NOTE***:- this is okay for very beginning, but getting user input and using it as such is [dangerous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/a2a4yykt(v=vs.100))!